# Timestamp1 is next day of timestamp2

Tags: java, timestamp

I have two timestamps and I want to check if the first timestamp is the next day (tomorrow) of the second timestamp.

** Next day not mean 24 hours, just next DAY_OF_MONTH. for example: timestamp of tomorrow 1 a.m. is the next day of today 10 p.m. (although it's only 3 hours) - therefore ts1 - ts2 < 86400 will not help here.

Firstly I think to extract the day of mounth and compare the delta but it's not good becuase the next day can be new month (or new year..)

The only solution I can think is:

```
Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
cal1.setTimeInMillis(1582783200000L);

Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
cal2.setTimeInMillis(1582727735000L);

cal2.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
cal1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) == cal2.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

But it's looks for me very ugly code...
Do you know another way to do it?

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Calendar`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `LocalDate` and other classes from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be slightly simplified with new date-time api

```
        ZoneId zone = ZoneId.systemDefault();
        boolean nextDay = 1 == ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(
                Instant.ofEpochMilli(1582727735000L).atZone(zone).truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS),
                Instant.ofEpochMilli(1582783200000L).atZone(zone).truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS));
```

Please note the result depends from a time zone. Thus the example refers to the system default, for the production code the explicit time zone should be applied.

Comment: Thank you very much!! I missed the time zone in the question, thanks to your highlight

Answer (score 2):

Do use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, as the other answer also does. My version would be:

```
    ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("Asia/Tel_Aviv");
    LocalDate d1 = Instant.ofEpochMilli(1_582_783_200_000L).atZone(zone).toLocalDate();
    LocalDate d2 = Instant.ofEpochMilli(1_582_727_735_000L).atZone(zone).toLocalDate();
    if (d2.plusDays(1).equals(d1)) {
        System.out.println("" + d1 + " is the day after " + d2);
    } else {
        System.out.println("" + d1 + " is *not* the day after " + d2);
    }
```

Output is:

> 2020-02-27 is the day after 2020-02-26

As edwgiz already said, the result depends on time zone, so make sure you specify the time zone you want. I prefer to write numbers with this many digits with underscore as thousand separator for readability. A `LocalDate` is a date in the proleptic Gregorian calendar without time of day, so comparing two such objects makes sure that we are ignoring time of day in the comparison.

PS Comparing day of month as in the question is insufficient in corner cases. It will yield true when comparing 27 February this year with 27 November last year. If we had wanted to use `Calendar`, we would have needed to compare era, year, month and day of month. In other words, it doesn’t offer nearly as good support for our job as java.time does.

**Tutorial link:** [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.

Comment: Thank you very much, for your answer, long explantion and the tutorial link!